# Intuitively and Mathematically Understanding the Order of Actions in Permutation GP vs in Dihereal GP

Tags: group-theory, permutations

I define $r$ to be one rotation clockwise, and s to be reflection on the 'horizontal' line (see the figure).

[image]

So I can make these bijections: (in clockwise order)
$$\begin{align*}
1,2,3,4,5,6 &\longleftrightarrow \mathrm{id}\\
1,6,5,4,3,2 &\longleftrightarrow s\\
6,1,2,3,4,5 &\longleftrightarrow r\\
5,6,1,2,3,4 &\longleftrightarrow r^2
\end{align*}$$
Note that each 'action' is taken separately on $\mathrm{id}$.

As an example, I want to evaluate $rsr^2$. In order to arrive at the same final figure, **on the number arrangements** I do $r^2$ first, then $s$ and finally $r$, but **on the figure** I must do $r$ first, then $s$ and finally $r^2$.

**WHY?** That is my question**s**

In other words, on the number arrangements,
$$1,2,3,4,5,6 \rightarrow 5,6,1,2,3,4 \rightarrow 3,2,1,6,5,4 \rightarrow 2,1,6,5,4,3,$$ and on the figure one rotation clockwise  $\rightarrow$ one reflection on the line $\rightarrow$ two rotations clockwise.

Well I know the fact that in permutation elements actions behave like in composing functions (right to left), but this is a superficial fact to understand intuitively **and** mathematically why 'actions' in $S_6$ and $D_6$ are **in reverse** manner?!

One interesting fact is that in $S_6$ actions are 'independent' (all come from $\mathrm{id}$) but in $D_6$ actions are 'dependent' (one happens 'on' the previous event). I can't figure out how this fact can help to solve my questions (both mathematically and intuitively understanding of what's going on).

EDIT - The text above doesn't use any complicated concepts in group theory (isomorphism, ...) and $D_6$ and $S_6$ are used only because of common use, and text is simpler than that. Having said that and since my knowledge is not high in group theory, I truly appreciate simple and clear explanation.

Comment: To clarify, is $S_6$ the symetric group of order 6, or that of order 6!=720? The latter one is standard, but it seems weird in this case.

Comment: What does **"each 'action' is taken separately on $\mathrm{id}$"** or **"all come from $\mathrm{id}$"** mean?

Comment: @wythagoras - $S_6$ is of order 6!=720.

Comment: @AlphaE Then I am afraid I don't understand the question.

Comment: @ZevChonoles - Thank you for your edit. I removed parentheses because they may be confusing with permutation (the numbers in order are numbers clockwise on the figure). -- it means that e.g. $5,6,1,2,3,4 \longleftrightarrow r^2$ is directly re-arrangements of numbers from $id$ and $1,6,5,4,3,2 \longleftrightarrow s$ is also **from** $id$, nothing to do with $r^2$ (I mean in defining the bijections).

Comment: @wythagoras - I am confused! "the symetric group of order 6, or that of order 6!=720" are [same](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Symmetric_group:S6) (?)

Comment: @AlphaE never mind, I first thought that you wanted to ask why the Dihedral group with 6 elements and the Symmetric group with 6 elements (S3) were isomorphic.

Comment: @wythagoras - thank you for your question since it inspired me to add edit in hope for a much better answer. :)

Comment: How does $s$ map $5,6,1,2,3,4$ to $3,2,1,6,5,4$? By your definitions, it should map $5,6,1,2,3,4$ to $5,4,3,2,1,6$.

Comment: @trb456 - By $s$, 1 and 4 are fixed and the figure flips. Why to 5,4,3,2,1,6? Since the previous action was 5,6,1,2,3,4 so it will be mapped to 3,2,1,6,5,4.

Comment: Your definition is incorrect. That line is supposed to be **fixed** horizontally, and you flip over it, which is what I did. To see that your definition is wrong, compute $rs$ and $sr$. They should not be equal ($D_6$ is nonabelian), but they are under your definition.

Comment: @trb456 - No! you're not right. In number arrangements ($S_6$) 1 and 4 are fixed by $s$ and in $D_6$ your are right which I have already considered it. In $D_6$ it is fixed horizontally and in $S_6$ it is fixed by numbers 1 and 4.

Comment: Then I join the others in not understanding your question.

Comment: @trb456 - the action of $s$ in "the number arrangements" method means that ordered numbers 1,2,3,4,5,6 change to 1,6,5,4,3,2. In "the number arrangements" method, forget about the figure. It's just like in $S_6$ only permutation of numbers.

Answer (score 0):

When you write a "number arrangement" $a,b,c,d,e,f$, you are interpreting it as, the number $a$ winds up in position $1$, $b$ winds up in position $2$, and so on.

But here's a different, equally valid representation: $a,b,c,d,e,f$ is now interpreted as, vertex $1$ winds up at position $a$, vertex $2$ winds up at position $b$, and so on. With this interpretation, $r$ corresponds to $2,3,4,5,6,1$ instead of $6,1,2,3,4,5$. I think that if you set things up that way, you'll find that $rsr^2$ works out by doing $r$, then $s$, then $r^2$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I wrote the final answer in : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1373136/why-composition-and-dihedral-group-have-reverse-order-of-operation/1376816#1376816